# Limit input box suggestion data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input box which I use to input data.
On that input box when I input a letter, it shows suggestion data with drop down for select.

When I enter 1 letter in the input field, that suggestion drop down data show big list. I want to limit that space with auto scroll.

I did it for now.

But if I put an exact height for it, it shows blank space like below.

[image: blank space]

I want to adjust height according to data like below.

[image: Auto adjust height]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post some code

Comment: Use max-height and overflow:scroll property in your css